# Why did Visual Studio stop giving the option to automatically add an Async method suffix?

Tags: visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-2017, naming-conventions, intellisense

[image]

Visual Studio 2017 used to underline async methods and give the option to add an Async suffix if they didn't already have one. If you look at [this tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PRIYANSHUAGRAWAL92.AsyncMethodNameFixer#overview) in the Visual Studio Marketplace you'll see exactly what I'm talking about. The only problem is that I never installed that tool, so I'm wondering how I had that functionality before and why it no longer seems to exist as a builtin option. You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#important-info-and-advice) that it's a recommended coding convention.

I checked the Visual Studio naming convention options to see if I could turn it back on in there but "async methods" wasn't on the list.

[image]

Does anyone know what changed and why? I"m using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 version 15.8.1

Comment: It's debatable, but `async` is becoming the standard, not the exception...

Comment: @jessehouwing - So do you remember when it used to do this?

Comment: Not really. I've had stylecop for Roslyn installed its pretty good in enforcing these kinds of naming things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the template I had been using had an analyzer installed that was doing it, so it was never a builtin feature after all. https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD200.md